# SQL LOAD DATA INFILE question

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, load-data-infile

How do I get the LOAD DATA INFILE command to skip certain fields.

Lets say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    junk CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    a ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And my file:

```
,name1,junk1,
,name2,junk2,
,name3,junk3,Y
```

does the statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile' INTO TABLE stuff FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

automatically skip the auto increment and deal with it properly? it seems to handle everything properly but this produces the following warnings:

```
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'a' at row 1
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 2
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 3
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'a' at row 3
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 4
```

removing the comma at the beginning doesn't input the data properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set id to NULL so it uses the auto-increment value.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile' 
INTO TABLE stuff 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
SET id = NULL;
```

I would also recommend removing the first comma and explicitly listing the columns in your file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile' 
INTO TABLE stuff 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name,junk,a)
SET id = NULL;
```